# Google Chrome: Aw, Snap crash on page containing webfonts

Tags: google-chrome, crash, webfonts

Does anyone know why Google Chrome is crashing when the user land on a page with webfonts

It does not happen all the time, but just too often

I'm just getting a blue screen page, and I have no clue why: The page is just fine when it's not coming from a redirect.

This is what I have found in the logs:

```
[3612:5872:17856358:INFO:buffered_resource_handler.cc(178)] To buffer: http://www.app.com/app/files/fonts/aller_lt-webfont.woff
[3612:5872:17856358:INFO:buffered_resource_handler.cc(178)] To buffer: http://www.app.com/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.woff
[3612:5872:17856358:INFO:buffered_resource_handler.cc(140)] Finished buffering http://www.app.com/app/files/fonts/aller_lt-webfont.woff
[3612:5872:17856358:INFO:buffered_resource_handler.cc(140)] Finished buffering http://www.app.com/app/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.woff
[3612:5872:17856545:WARNING:passive_log_collector.cc(175)] The passive log data has grown larger than expected, resetting
[3612:5872:17856607:WARNING:passive_log_collector.cc(175)] The passive log data has grown larger than expected, resetting
```

this is the code crashing: (.css)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AllerDisplay';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/AllerDisplay.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/allerdisplay-webfont.svg#webfontLZ8nc4vC') format('svg');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_ltit-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_ltit-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_ltit-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_ltit-webfont.svg#webfontwJcwR5d9') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.svg#webfontGly2h2wa') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_lt-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_lt-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_lt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_lt-webfont.svg#webfontoaLI8hBJ') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_it-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_it-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_it-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_it-webfont.svg#webfontEbJrfJy1') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bd-webfont.svg#webfontmJTweXww') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller';
    src: url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/app/uad/files/fonts/aller_bdit-webfont.svg#webfontO1egShyd') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.johnnydeppweb.com/

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS&sort=&id=62531

Comment: I'm having some problem, only not with one font in particular. Any font used with @font-face causes the "aw snap" about once every 30 page loads or so.